# R function equal to excel CHIINV

Tags: r, chi-squared, excel

I'm looking for a function which do the same thing as excel's CHIINV.
From Microsoft documentation, the definition of CHIINV is
Returns the inverse of the right-tailed probability of the chi-squared distribution

For example
`=CHIINV(0.2,2)` return 3.21

The closest function I can found in R is
geoR's dinvchisq
However,

`dinvchisq(0.2,2)` return 1.026062

Please help!

Comment: try `?Chisquare` (`?`=help) or `??"chi square"` (`??`=search) similarly for any other distribution, which shows you the function calls for cdf, pdf, inverse cdf and random number generation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is [?qchisq](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Chisquare.html). This takes a probability and a degrees of freedom, and outputs the associated quantile.  Consider:

```
> qchisq(p=0.2, df=2, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 3.218876
```

Furthermore, according the the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/geoR/docs/InvChisquare), `dinvchisq()` is the density function (the height of the pdf at a given quantile) of the *inverse* of the chi-squared distribution.  That is, 1/dchisq().  You need the quantile function, not the density function, and you don't want the inverse of the chi-squared distribution (although the confusion seems natural coming from Excel's function).